# How to show the identity $\int_0^T \int_{\Gamma(t)}f(s,t)\;dsdt = \int_S f(\sigma)(1+(\mathbf w \cdot \mathbf n)^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\;d\sigma$?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

I am reading [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6155).

Let $\Gamma(t)$ be a smooth closed connected oriented hypersurface for each $t \in [0,T]$. Define the set $$S = \bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\Gamma(t) \times \{t\}.$$

On page 5 of the document, the authors say

> the identity 
>   $$\int_0^T \int_{\Gamma(t)}f(s,t)\;dsdt = \int_S f(\sigma)(1+(\mathbf w \cdot \mathbf n)^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\;d\sigma$$
>   holds

where $\mathbf n$ is the unit normal on $\Gamma(t)$ and $\mathbf w$ is a velocity field that advects $\Gamma(t)$ (these definitions found in page 2).

**QUESTION** How does one prove this identity? In fact, I thought that
$$\int_0^T \int_{\Gamma(t)}f(s,t)\;dsdt = \int_S f(\sigma)\;d\sigma$$
is supposed to be true.

The square rooted term reminds me of using a parametrisation, but not sure what or how. I wonder what it even means to write down a product integral as on the RHS...

I have also posted this [on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157064/how-to-show-the-identity-int-0t-int-gammatfs-t-dsdt-int-s-f-sigm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a baby version of the coarea formula, which is a curvilinear version of the Fubini's theorem.

By breaking $\Gamma(0)$ into small pieces we assume that we calculate in a small local coordinate with variable $x \in B$ and metric $g_{ij}$. Then locally $(x, t)$ is a chart of $S$ given by $(x, t)\mapsto (\Phi_x(t), t)$, where $\Phi_x(t)$ solves the ODE

$\Phi'_x(t) = w(\Phi_x(t))$.

(Note that $x\mapsto \Phi_x(t)$ gives a local coordinate for $\Gamma(t)$. With respect to this coordinate on $S$, the volume element is given by

$$ d\sigma = \sqrt{1+ (w\cdot n)^2} \sqrt{\det(g^t_{ij})} dx$$

where $g^t_{ij}$ is the metric on $\Gamma(t)$. (The reason is that, as $(w, 1) = ((w\cdot n)n, 1) + (w^t, 0)$ where $w^t$ is the tengential part (w.r.t. $\Gamma(t)$) of $w$). Then

$$\int_S f(\sigma) (1+ (w\cdot n)^2)^{-1/2} d\sigma = \int^T_0 \int_{B} f(\Phi_x(t), t)  \sqrt{\det(g^t_{ij})} dx dt= \int^T_0 \int_{\Gamma(t)} f(s, t) ds dt$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I don't understand why you get that expression for $d\sigma$. I understand that $(w,1)$ has the representation you give it but why is $(w,1)$ used in the expression for $d\sigma$? And if you are taking the modulus of $(w,1)$ what happened to the $(w^t, 0)$ part?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the area element $dA$ at a point $x\in \Gamma(t)$ is the area of the parallelogram $P$ spanned by the coordinate vectors  $v_1, \cdots, v_k$ ($k=\dim \Gamma(t)$). Now to calculate $d\sigma$, we calculate the volume of parallelogram spanned by $v_1, \cdots , v_k$ together with $ (w, 1)$. The area is $||(w, 1)^\perp||\cdot dA$, wherer $(w, 1)^\perp$ is the normal component (wrt to $\Gamma(t)$) of $(w, 1)$.